# Why is the text getting appended to the wrong html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Overview:** I have an editable div section. Below the div, there is a button which creates a span element, inserts the text "tag" in the span element and finally appends the span element in that editable div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
        #sample-div
        {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: black;
            height:100px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTags()
        {
            var tag = document.createElement("span");
            tag.className = "tag"
            tag.innerHTML = "tag";
            $('#sample-div').append(tag);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="sample-div" contenteditable="true"></div>
 <input type="button" value="date" id="sample-tags" onclick="addTags()">
</body>
</html>
```

**Observation:** I click on the button, the span element is added to the div as expected

```
<div id="sample-div" contenteditable="true">
   <span class="tag">tag</span>
</div>
<input type="button" value="date" id="sample-tags" onclick="addTags()">
```

However, after I start typing inside the div, I noticed the following:

```
<div id="sample-div" contenteditable="true">
   <span class="tag">tag this is a continuation</span>
</div>
```

My **expectation** was:

```
<div id="sample-div" contenteditable="true">
   <span class="tag">tag</span> this is a continuation
</div>
```

So, my question is why the text "this is a continuation" also getting appended inside the span element? How do I achieve the one stated under my expectation?

Comment: I think all text within a contenteditable div needs to be within a child tag of some sort.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, not true: https://jsfiddle.net/mdeenbvv/1/

Comment: Where did the text "this is a continuation" come from?

Comment: "this is a continuation" text is the text I type inside the editable div element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to set the `contentEditable` attribute of your span to be `false`:

```
function addTags() {
    var tag = document.createElement("span");
    tag.className = "tag"
    tag.innerHTML = "tag";
    tag.contentEditable = false;
    $('#sample-div').append(tag);
}
```

Side note: since you are using jQuery you don't need to manually create the tag:

```
function addTags() {
   var tag = '<span class="tag" contenteditable="false">tag</span>'
   $('#sample-div').append(tag);
}
```